# HTTP 500 error upon deploying application to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google App Engine to deploy a test application. The deployment works fine and when I point my browser to the following URL, I receive an HTTP 500 error:
https://test-gae-365706.uc.r.appspot.com/

My application code is as follows:

```
const http = require('http');

const port = 8080;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Do not have an inflated sense of yourself. You are just food for worms.');
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

My `app.yaml` file is as follows:

```
runtime: nodejs10
```

My `package.json` file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "app-engine",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node app.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x.x"  
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When I run `glcoud app deploy`, I do not get any errors, but when I point my browser to the URL, I get the HTTP 500 error:
`Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.`

In the navigation pane, when I go to the **Instances** page, I see that no instance has been created. Could this be the problem?

Please let me know what is it that I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need a start script in package.json. Based on your test script, it would be something like -

`"start": "node app.js"`

See a [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/3bb14ef7c23305613bbfe04f03d3b83f6a120e1a/appengine/building-an-app/build) Node App from Google

2. You're using the variable `${hostname}` but you haven't defined it. You need to define it and provide a value like you did for `port`